# What is wrong with this proof in topology?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a $T_4$-space and $M \subset X$, then $M$ is a subspace that is also $T_4$.

Proof: If $A,B$ are closed in $M$, then $A=W_A \cap M$ and $B = W_B \cap M$ for some closed sets $W_A,W_B$. Since $X$ is $T_4$, we can separate them by open sets $W_A\subset U_A$, $W_B\subset U_B$ and therefore $A,B$ are separated by $U_A \cap M, U_B \cap M$.

Comment: $W_A$ and $W_B$ need not be disjoint.

Comment: Somewhat related is [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/754775/8348).