# When a subspace of compact spaces is normal

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, separation-axioms

According to my previous question, we know that a closed subspace of a hausdorff compact space is normal. I am looking for a condition $*$, such that the following statment is true.

> A subspace of a hausdorff campact space is normal if and only if it has $*$  condition.

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220478/examples-for-subspace-of-a-normal-space-which-is-not-normal) seems relevant

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an easy necessary condition, besides the trivial "normal" itself, or some reformulation thereof. What *is* known is thet $F_\sigma$ (countable unions of closed sets) subsets of normal spaces are normal in the subspace topology, and there are examples of open subspaces of compact Hausdorff spaces that are not normal; even removing a point from such a space can leave a non-normal result.  If a normal space $X$ has the property that all open subspaces are normal, then all of its subspaces are normal, so openness is the "test case" , as it were.