# Locally Compact Hausdorff Space That is Not Normal

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Someone told me that locally compact Hausdorff spaces (unlike compact ones) need not be normal. Can one give me please such an example? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/), a database-driven version of Steen and Seebach's *[Counterexamples in Topology](http://books.google.com/books/about/Counterexamples_in_Topology.html?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC)*, lists the following locally compact Hausdorff (i.e. T2) spaces that are not normal. You can view the [search result](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Weakly%20Locally%20Compact%2B%24T_2%24%2BNormal) to learn more about these spaces.

$[0,1) \times I^I$

Deleted Tychonoff Plank

Rational Sequence Topology

Thomas’s Plank

Answer (score 3):

The space $X$ described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145786/12042) is a fairly simple separable, locally compact Tikhonov space that is not normal, provided that the set $\mathscr{D}$ is chosen to have cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak c$, as described at the end of the answer. The non-normality follows from [Jones’s lemma](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/jones-lemma/), which implies that a separable, normal space cannot contain a closed discrete subset of of cardinality $2^\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53300/locally-compact-hausdorff-space-that-is-not-normal) you can find some examples ...