# Different versions of Urysohn's Lemma

Tags: general-topology, functions

In short, I encountered two different versions of Urysohn Lemma, which I shall present here:

Version 1: [Big Rudin, 2.12, page 39]: Suppose X is a locally compact Hausdorff space, V is open in X, $K \subset V$ and K is compact. Then there exists an $f \in C_c(X)$ such that $K \prec f \prec V$ with the following notation:

- $f \in C_c(X)$ if f is continuous and has compact support
- $K \prec f$ if $0 \le f(x) \le 1$ for all x and $f(K) = 1$
- $f \prec V$ if $0 \le f(x) \le 1$ for all x and the support of f lies in V.

Version 2: [Munkres, Topology, page 201]: Let X be a normal space, let A and B be disjoint closed subsets of X. Let [a,b] a closed interval in the real line. Then there exists a continuous map $f: X \rightarrow [a,b]$ such that $f(x) = a \forall x \in A$ and $f(x) = b \forall x \in B$

My question is that which version is "stronger"? I've tried to deduce whether one version is the consequence of another, but it seems not the case. As far as I read through both books, each version has distinct applications, so how the difference in the initial condition affect their application?

Answer (score 4):

The theorem in Munkres is the one usually referred to as Uryso(h)n’s lemma; I consider Rudin’s use of the term incorrect. The two results are not directly comparable: a locally compact Hausdorff space need not be normal, and a normal space need not be locally compact.

> **Added:** However, as Andreas Blass reminds me in the comments, one can deduce Rudin’s result from Uryson’s lemma by passing to the one-point compactification $X^*$ of a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$: it’s a compact Hausdorff space and therefore normal, and a compact subset of $X$ is still closed in $X^*$.

Answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235729/locally-compact-hausdorff-space-that-is-not-normal) give some examples of locally compact Hausdorff spaces that are not normal; $\Bbb Q$ is a familiar example of a normal (indeed metrizable) space that is not locally compact. The space of irrationals is another.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the one-point compactification of a locally compact space is a compact Hausdorff space and therefore normal. So one could deduce Rudin's version from Munkres's by applying the latter to $K$ and the complement of $V$ in the one-point compactification.

Comment: With the hint of Andreas, I'll present my idea, hopefully it's correct. Let X' be the one point compactification of X, then X' is compact Hausdorff (and therefore normal), therefore one can choose a continuous map $f: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(K) = 1$ and $f(X' - V) = 0$. The support of f is closed, and therefore it's compact. So it seems the crucial difference is compactness, which is not required in Munkres' version.

Comment: @Linh: Yes, that’s right.